# Symfony manifest asset versioning creates multiple files

Tags: manifest, assets, versioning, manifest.json, webpack-encore

I'm using Symfony (v4.1) for one of my projects.

As I wanted to try out the manifest versioning I enabled it on dev environment. I'm pretty sure it's not a good practice as it takes more time to build the assets up, but well... curiosity.

I realized that while using manifest versioning I'm building up the new asset every time I change something, which is correct, but it seems like the old asset is not being removed.

I'm not sure if it's a desired behavior, but is there any way to remove the old file by configuring the Symfony's Encore? Or am I not understanding this correctly and the old file is still needed for something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No old files are not needed. There is the 'cleanup-webpack-plugin' you can enable by using:

```
Encore
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
```